# Java mySQL queries not working with variables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

For some reason when my java code attempts to execute a query that is using a variable I receive a syntax error.

```
    String query = "SELECT userName, email, address FROM users,requests"
                + "WHERE requestingUser = userID AND rideID = ?";
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setInt(1, rideID);
    results = ps.executeQuery()
```

This code produces the following MySQL error:

```
    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= userID AND rideID = 34' at  
    line 1"
```

I have tried this both with and without using PreparedStatments, and I only receive an error for those queries for which I pass in a variable. Simple queries like "SELECT field FROM table" work fine. I feel like I am going insane, I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What is `requestingUser`?

Comment: Also, what is your JOIN criteria?

Comment: They are all integer values, so I don't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a space between requests and WHERE